# use substring function in group by clause in AWS Athena table

Tags: amazon-athena

My 'date_validation' column is in string type and display as '2018-05-22 13:38:59.0' so to convert it to date, had to use substring and 'date_parse' functions to have something like '2014-02-26 00:00:00.000'.

I need to have a count of boardings grouping by date_validation, because there are lots of validations for one day. But cannot do that since its giving error when I use group by as below.

```
 SELECT
    DATE_PARSE(SUBSTR(date_validation, 1, 10), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    run_route_code,
    stop_label,
    COUNT(boardings)
 FROM "raw_XX"."validations"
 WHERE
    run_route_code = 'XXX'
GROUP BY
    DATE_PARSE(SUBSTR(date_validation, 1, 10), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    run_route_code,
    stop_label
ORDER BY
    date_validation;
```

Error is saying

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:107: '"date_validation"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause'

If I use date_validation column directly in group by clause, it's not grouping and just display all values per one day.
please give me an advice.

Please note that cannot do any changes into the date as its raw table and huge partitioned table which is sitting on Raw bucket now.

Comment: What is the difference between `operation_date_validation` and `date_validation`?

Comment: @Tim,
Sorry, my apologies. It should be date_validation. I corrected it. consider the column as 'date_validation'.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is actually being caused by the `ORDER BY` clause, which refers to the `date_validation` column.  The issue here is that by the time the `ORDER BY` gets evaluated, only the date/substring is available, not the original `date_validation` column.  Use the `DATE_PARSE(...)` version and your query should work:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_PARSE(SUBSTR(date_validation, 1, 10), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    run_route_code,
    stop_label,
    COUNT(boardings)
 FROM "raw_XX"."validations"
 WHERE
    run_route_code = 'XXX'
GROUP BY
    DATE_PARSE(SUBSTR(date_validation, 1, 10), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    run_route_code,
    stop_label
ORDER BY
    DATE_PARSE(SUBSTR(date_validation, 1, 10), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Note: You could also just use `ORDER BY 1` here, which is abbreviated, but I offer the solution above because it makes clear the source of/solution to the error.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Woow.. It worked. MAny Thanks for that.
One thing, I'm still cannot counted by date.. :(
Still results appears as below.

              validation_date             count
                  
1 2020-12-29 00:00:00.000 11
2 2020-12-29 00:00:00.000 66
3 2020-12-29 00:00:00.000 28